# Two centrals, one peripheral

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible for a BTLE (4.0) peripheral to remain advertising after a central has connected, and could another central then also connect simultaneously?

I can find nothing addressing this clearly, while it is clear that a central can connect to n-many peripherals at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Bluetooth Core Specification Version 4 says this on page 200:

"The Periph- eral role is optimized for devices that support a single connection and are less complex than central devices. Devices supporting the peripheral role only require Controllers that support the Controller’s slave role. The Central role supports multiple connections and is the initiator for all connections with devices in the peripheral role. Devices supporting the central role require a Controller that support the Controller’s master role and generally supports more complex functions compared to the other LE GAP roles."

Which looks like a no to me, but it's not quite as specific as you might have hoped.

You can find a list of the adopted Bluetooth specifications from bluetooth.com (formerly bluetooth.org) at this link:

> https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications

The quote above comes from Core Version 4.0 page 200 and is also available in the Core Version 4.2 on page 98.

Comment: Great answer! Add a link to PDF for posterity?

Comment: Found PDF Here: http://developer.bluetooth.org/KnowledgeCenter/TechnologyOverview/Documents/Core_SPEC.pdf (2,302 pages)

Comment: @JeffLambert That PDF is a broken link. :(

Answer (score 3):

The "Bluetooth specification Version 4.2 [Vol 3, Part C]" states the following aspects:

•   Page 231:
2.2.2.3 Peripheral Role
“Any device that accepts the establishment of an LE physical link using any of
the connection establishment procedures as defined in Section 9 is referred to
as being in the Peripheral role.”

•   From section 9 at the "Limited Discoverable Mode" section at page 351:
9.2.3.2 Conditions
"While a device is in the Peripheral role the device may support the limited
discoverable mode. While a device is in the Broadcaster, Observer or Central
role the device shall not support the limited discoverable mode."
...
"While in the limited discoverable mode the device shall send advertising event
types with the advertising data including the Flags AD type as defined in [Core
Specification Supplement], Part A, Section 1.3 with all the following flags set as
described"
"The device shall remain in limited discoverable mode until a connection is
established or the Host terminates the mode."

•   From section 9 at the "General Discoverable Mode" section at page 352:
9.2.4.2 Conditions
"While a device is in the Peripheral role the device may support the general
discoverable mode. While a device is in the Broadcaster, Observer or Central
role the device shall not support the general discoverable mode."
...
"While in general discoverable mode the device shall send advertising events
with the advertising data including the Flags AD data type as defined in [Core
Specification Supplement], Part A, Section 1.3 with all the following flags set as
described"
...
"The device shall remain in general discoverable mode until a connection is
established or the Host terminates the mode."

The standard is assertive you have to stop advertising when the connection is established.